# JQuery blur function not working second time

Tags: jquery

Hi i have a textbox which has "enter ur name" at loading. When focus on it, it become empty and if I dont type anything and the blur it change again to "Enter ur name". This works fine for many times. But the problem is if I focus and enter something and then removed the characters, the textbox is empty. But as to my logic if textbox is empty it should have "enter " your name. JQUERY here is my code. Pls suggest something.

```
  $(document).ready(function (){
    var name='Enter the name';
    $('input[type="text"]').attr('value',name).focus(function(){
            if($(this).val() == name){
                $(this).attr('value','');
            }
    }).blur(function(){
            if($(this).val() == ''){
                $(this).attr('value',name);
            }
    })
  });
```

Comment: I'd say you should replace `.attr('value',name)` with `.val(name)`

Comment: You should consider using the placeholder attribute instead.

Comment: What @karim79 said... you have some code for crossbrowser compatibility here: http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html

Comment: @techfoobar I have tried ur suggestion. The problem I told was removed.But again some other problem. When second time I focus, the "Enter ur name" is not removed...

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works fine.....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var msg= 'Enter email.....';
    $('input[type="email"]').attr('value',msg).focus(function(){
            if($(this).val()==msg){
                    $(this).val('');

            }

    }).blur(function(){

            if($(this).val()==''){
            //alert($(this).val());
                    $(this).val(msg);

            }


    });

 });
```